# Selenium unable to find element after <script> tag

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I recently asked a question for a  tag which I couldn't get the data with find_element(By.ID,"id"). As I looked further, I realized that the problem was not there.

I tested tag by tag:

and many   and other.
After a  tag I can't access to these data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
cerbetNav.setConfirmableActionMessage('Data loss without backup.');
</script>
```

I'm stuck at this place, is there a way to retrieve the  tag or not?
I don't know where and how to access the setConfirmableActionMessage function, is it possible to do something?

I'm using Python 3.10 and Selenium 4.3.0

Thank you !!

Comment: is `soup.select('script')` not working?

Comment: That's not after the script tag, that's inside it.

Comment: Do I need to use BeautifulSoup ?